# Reading a string from file in C

Tags: c, string, file-io, int

I have recently learnt about using I/O files in C, and one of my book exercises asks me to read lines of pairs of number and add them, then print them to an output file.

What I mean is:

If the input file looks like:

```
12 13
24 26
23 13
```

the output file will be:

```
25
50
36
```

I have tried reading it as a string using:

```
fscanf(in, "%s", &string); //in is the input file pointer
```

but it doesn't work (causes a seg. fault)

My problem is that I am unable to take in the lines of pairs of numbers using the `fscanf` function, as I do not know how many lines there are in the input file.

Thus, my question is: ***How do I read an input file containing an amount of lines if I do not know how many lines there are? Can I read it as a string?***

Thank you in advanced.

Michael

Comment: We can't debug or fix code we can't see.

Comment: You read your file line by line in a loop until you reach the end of the file (`eof` function).

Comment: Hint: you don't need to know the exact number of lines, just read a line, process it and repeat until EOF.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I just want to know how to take in a certain amount of lines using scanf

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo Thanks, I'll think about the hint

Comment: @MichaelFerashireSilva We need to see how you're using `scanf` to tell you. The answer *might* be to check the return value of `scanf`, but it's hard to be sure without seeing your code.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I have added the line of code I have tried to use to read in the sets of numbers.

Comment: @MichaelFerashireSilva That doesn't tell us anything. What type is `string`? How is its value set before that line of code? Where and how is the memory the string is stored in allocated? That's the code we need to see.

Answer (score -1):

Here's some working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

main()
{
int a,b; 
FILE *fp = fopen("filename.txt", "r"); //open file for reading
FILE *f  = fopen("file.txt", "w");     //open file for writing

while (!feof (fp))                     //reading file until end of file
{
  fscanf (fp, "%d", &a);  
  fscanf (fp, "%d", &b); 
  int sum = a + b;
  fprintf(f, "%d\n", sum);  //writing summation to a file
}

fclose(f);  //close files 
fclose(fp);        
return 0;
}
```

Just create filename.txt and write numbers in it. And create blank file.txt.

Comment: You're expecting `feof` to predict the future and tell you whether a future read will succeed or not. It cannot do that.

Comment: As @DavidSchwartz this method of taking in the sets of numbers doesn't work